# Decorator functions in classes. Should each instantiation result in decorator function being run again?

Tags: python, decorator, nose

I have read around; and the closest I can find is a mention that using generator functions and decorator functions are not supported

`class  getsize`  with methods: `setUp` `tearDown` and `getfilesize`
With the nose `with_setup(setUp,tearDown)`.

I also have a distinct generation function (in the same file) that 
uses a loop to create an  instance of the  `getsize class` and call the method `getfilesize`.

When I run the file via `nosetests;` I find that the @with_setup is only run done when nose runs the class.

When I run the generator function; it never gets accessed.  As a work around I add in calls to the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods; and I get the expected results.This is really bugging me and I have made a considerable effort to track down an answer.

*[Additional] This is the code section:*

```
  class Test_getFileSize:
    import logging
    from nose.tools import with_setup
    log = logging.getLogger("Test getfilesize")
        def setUp(self):
            print " running Setup",self.testsize
            with open(self.mytestfile, "wb") as out:
            out.seek(self.testsize-1)
            out.write('0')
            out.close()
        def tearDown(self):
            import os
            print "Running tearDown"
            os.remove(self.mytestfile)
    @with_setup(setUp,tearDown)
    def test_getFileSize(self):`
```

*[rest of this method and the init follow but are not pertinent to the question.*

Comment: Is this a class decorator or a function decorator?

Comment: from nose import with_setup
docstring says: Decorator to add setup and/or teardown methods to a test function

Comment: This is a method decorator which the nose docs say is supported.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is mentioning, and I am restating for further clarity there is no need to add a @with_setup decorator to a test function. You have already added setup and teardown functions to the class and they will automatically be run before and after the test.

From the nose docs:

> Note that with_setup is useful only for test functions, not for test
>   methods or inside of TestCase subclasses.

Now in your case you have with_setup within a TestCase class. The nose documentation explicitly mentions that this does not work

But you already solved the puzzle, now just remove the @with_setup decorator and you're finished. Your code should ultimately look something like this

```
class Test_getFileSize:
    def setUp(self):
        print " running Setup",self.testsize
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
       ...
       print "Running tearDown"
       ...

    def test_getFileSize(self):
       ...
```